# Highchart and php

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

Hi guys i m trying to pass value from my php to highchart dataset but its not working help needed.

```
<?php $count2=$decode[nextPage][totalResults];
    echo("<input type=hidden name=aaqib value=".$count.">");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var chart;
                var j= $("input[name=aaqib]").val();
                var k=100;

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container'
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            tickInterval: 1
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            type: 'logarithmic',
                            minorTickInterval: 0.1
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
                            pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
                        },

                        series: [{
                            data: [j,k,
                            pointStart: 1
                        }]
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hi guys i m trying to pass value from my php to highchart dataset but its not working help needed.

i need to use value of J and K in data so that they are shown in highcharts

Comment: possibly just a copy/paste error, but `data: [j,k,` is missing a trailing `]` to end the array

Comment: yaa i guess it got deleted while pasting it

Comment: @user1457334 What's the error ?

Answer (score 3):

Store your `php` vars into a `js` vars and then pass to `highcharts`.

Fix the following too.
`echo('<input type="hidden" name="aaqib" value="{$count}"/>');`

Update according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801515/highchart-and-php/11801748#comment15683744_11801748) comment.

```
series: [{
    data: [[j,k]]
}]
```

Tthis [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-log-axis/) should help you.

Comment: that would indead be the easiest and cleanest solution. inside your javascript something like `var j = <?php echo($count) ?>;´

Comment: Yes, but he won't be able to have the js in a different file in that case?

Comment: i did this  var j= $("input[name=aaqib]").val(); if u have a look at the code above ..but its not taking value of j then

Comment: @JugalThakkar Yes you can, this case you'll have to use a function that init your values and store into an object which's declared on your .js

Comment: @user1457334 Are you sure your input is being created? I think not.

Comment: @JugalThakkar Right, my bad :P

Comment: guys i m getting the value in j in js i just need the right syntax of putting it in data

Answer (score 0):

why are you echoing the `input` above your doctype declaration? I think that belongs inside your body. And you should also '-signs around the attribute values in you echo. something like this:

```
<?php $count2=$decode[nextPage][totalResults];
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='aaqib' value='$count'>");
?>
```

Some browsers might threat this correctly, but it's actualy invalid html